# Why does Rails form multiple: true change submitted param form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-activestorage

I'm playing with ActiveStorage and trying to upload some files locally. Everything works great with the code below, but only if I remove `multiple: true` from the form. When it is on the form, I get an unpermitted param "files" error in the console. The unpermitted param comes from the way the form is submitting the hash.

Without `multiple: true` the hash lists attachments as an array (this is the working version):

`"article"=>{"files"=>[#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb4e8e287f0`

But with it turned on it it removes the array:

`"article"=>{"files"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fb4eb07b7d0`

What is causing this form behavior and how can I fix it?

I got the code sample from [Engine Yard](https://www.engineyard.com/blog/active-storage) and here is the project code:

```
<h3>Attach files to this post</h3>
<%= form_with model: @article, local: true do |f|  %>
    <div class="form-row">
        <%= f.label :file_upload, 'Attach a file' %>
        <%= f.file_field :files, multiple: true %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<h3>Attached files</h3>
<% @article.files.each do |file| %>
    <%= link_to file.blob.filename, url_for(file) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: How does your controller params look? You should set the `:files` params to look for an array when you use `multiple: true`.

Comment: I changed the params to read `params.require(:article).permit(:author, :text, [:files])` and that does format the passed params to match the working example, but I still get unpermitted param "files"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `multiple: true` you need to permit an array explicit in the `article_params` for `:files`:

For example:

```
params.require(:article).permit(:author, :text, files: [])
```

You can read more under [Action Controller](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html)

Good luck!